# Download Fuchsia source --ERROR: Project integration(integration) contains uncommitted changes

Tags: fuchsia

After going through the installation steps mentioned at https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/get-started/get_fuchsia_source.

The error message was as shown below -

```
yeah@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/Yewon/Desktop$ curl -s "https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/HEAD/scripts/bootstrap?format=TEXT" | base64 --decode | bash
cipd bootstrapped to path:"/mnt/c/Users/Yewon/Desktop/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin/cipd"
Please add /mnt/c/Users/Yewon/Desktop/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin to your PATH
[21:47:29.755] WARN: Please opt in or out of analytics collection. You will receive this warning until an option is selected.
To check what data we collect run: jiri init -show-analytics-data
To opt-in run: jiri init -analytics-opt=true "/mnt/c/Users/Yewon/Desktop/fuchsia"
To opt-out run: jiri init -analytics-opt=false "/mnt/c/Users/Yewon/Desktop/fuchsia"

[21:47:29.962] WARN: Please opt in or out of analytics collection. You will receive this warning until an option is selected.
To check what data we collect run: jiri init -show-analytics-data
To opt-in run: jiri init -analytics-opt=true "/mnt/c/Users/Yewon/Desktop/fuchsia"
To opt-out run: jiri init -analytics-opt=false "/mnt/c/Users/Yewon/Desktop/fuchsia"

[21:47:30.314] Updating all projects
ERROR: Project integration(integration) contains uncommitted changes:
Commit or discard the changes and try again.

[21:52:02.015] WARN: Projects with local changes and/or not on JIRI_HEAD:
integration (integration): (Has changes) (Not on JIRI_HEAD)

To force an update to JIRI_HEAD, you may run 'jiri runp git checkout JIRI_HEAD'
[22:12:03.123] Jiri hooks are not run due to fatal errors when updating projects or packages
ERROR: Project integration(integration) contains uncommitted changes:
Commit or discard the changes and try again.
```

Could anyone share how to fix it?

I'm trying to install Fuchsia on a Khadas VIM3 board by following https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/hardware/khadas-vim3.

Comment: Did you get it working? I did some major updates to the VIM3 guide 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

This may have been a temporary issue with the latest `HEAD` checkout at the time you attempted it. If you continue to experience this, the following message in your error log indicates that you may be trying to run the bootstrap script on a machine that already has a copy of the Fuchsia source tree:

```
[21:47:30.314] Updating all projects
ERROR: Project integration(integration) contains uncommitted changes:
Commit or discard the changes and try again.
```

That states that the project (`integration`) already exists in your local checkout and can't be automatically updated to the latest `HEAD`.

If you want to run bootstrap, ensure you aren't overwriting any previous checkouts on your machine. If you already have the source and you just need to update the configuration for VIM3, simply follow the instructions in the guide you linked to get the proper `fx set` command.